# Populating Dropdown using user's choice with Spring, Ajax & JSP

Tags: java, ajax, spring, jsp

I have a problem in JSP form:

I need to populate a Dropdown list of student by user's choice of students group. But it doesn't work: the Dropdown box still empty.

*Code of `studentBar.jsp`:*

```html
<%--suppress JSUnresolvedFunction --%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<c:url var="loadStudentsByGroup" value="/loadStudents" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#groupId').change(
            function() {
                $.get('${loadStudentsByGroup}', {
                    groupId : $(this).val(),
                    ajax : 'true'
                }, function(data) {
                    var html = '<option value="">Первый элемент</option>';
                    var len = data.length;
                    for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                        html += '<option value="' + data[i].studentsId + '">'
                            + data[i].stFamily + '</option>';
                    }
                    html += '</option>';
                    $('#studentId').html(html);
                });
            });
    });
</script>

<body>
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="studentLogin" action="checkStudent">
    <form:select id="groupId" path="">
        <c:forEach items="${groupList}" var="group">
            <form:option value="${group.groupId}" >${group.groupName}</form:option>
        </c:forEach><br/>
    </form:select>
    <form:select id="studentId" path="name">
    </form:select>
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

*Code of `controller.java`*

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/loadStudents", headers = "Accept=*/*", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
List<StudentsEntity> loadStudents(@RequestParam(value = "groupId", required = true) Integer groupId) throws IllegalStateException {
    List<StudentsEntity> stList = loadStudent(groupId);
    return stList;
}
```

*Code of `loadStudent` function:*

```
public static List<StudentsEntity> loadStudent(Integer grId){
    Session session = getSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery("FROM StudentsEntity where stGroup="+grId);
    List<StudentsEntity> res = query.list();
    session.close();
    return res;
}
```